# move coupon field and button to cart-totals

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to move the coupon field to `car-totals.php`, but the button doesn't work, so I assume that I need to require some function or something, I kind of new in php and woocommerce

This is the code that I'm moving from `cart.php` to `cart-totals.php`..

```
<?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
        <div class="coupon">
            <h2>Aplica tu descuento exclusivo</h2>
            <div class="text-box-cupon">Si esta es tu segunda compra no olvides de usar tu cupon de descuento exlusivo. <a href="#" class="link-ferretti">Mayor información</a></div>

            <label for="coupon_code" class="ocultar"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>:</label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text cupon-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Código de cupón', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <input type="submit" class="button cupon-button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Aplicar cupón', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>

        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, so there is no way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy enough to do. The coupon is really just part of a form that is really a table with a header row and item description rows and a coupon row. Create a new form by removing the header row, item description rows and leaving just the coupon row. Insert this form into the cart totals section. This should yield:

```
<?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
    <form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="coupon">
            <label for="coupon_code"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
        </div>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

which I think just embeds what you already have into the necessary parent form (sorry, I cannot read Spanish). Note that coupon processing is done by AJAX so it is necessary to keep the 'Apply Coupon' button.